# Using the 'DataView' Wicket when I delete one item the entire list is excluded

Tags: java, button, wicket, dataview

I have a problem in 'DataView' do 'Wicket' ... I add some files to this DataView, and so far so good, when I delete a file is that the problem, if I delete any file that does not it is the first rule ... but if I try to delete the first item it excludes all other low sequentially ... anyone has seen something?

follows my code below:

```
  //Principal panel

   private class PanelPrincipalAnexo extends WebMarkupContainer
   {
    public PanelPrincipalAnexo(String id)
    {
        super(id);

        formUpload = getFormUpload();
        add(formUpload);
        formUpload.add(getDataViewAnexos("anexos"));
    }
  }




  //creating the FormUpload
  private FileUploadForm getFormUpload() {
    return new FileUploadForm("formUpload", new PropertyModel<List<FileUpload>>(this, "uploads"));
  }





  private DataView<ProgramaAnexo> getDataViewAnexos(String id) {

    return new DataView<ProgramaAnexo>(id, new AnexoProvider()) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item<ProgramaAnexo> item) {

            item.add(new Label("tipoArquivo"));
            item.add(new Label("nomeAnexo"));
            item.add(new Label("tamanhoArquivoEmMB")); 
            item.add(getButtonRemove(item));

        }
    };
}







 public AjaxSubmitLink getButtonRemove(Item<ProgramaAnexo> item) {
    AjaxSubmitLink button = new AjaxSubmitLink("btnRemoverBem", form) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
            actionRemoverKit(target,item);
        }
    };
    return button;
}





 private void actionRemoverKit(AjaxRequestTarget  target,Item<ProgramaAnexo> item) {

    ProgramaAnexo bemRemove=item.getModelObject();
    int cont=0;
    for(ProgramaAnexo bem:list)
    {            
        if(bemRemove.getBem().getId().intValue()==bem.getBem().getId().intValue())
        {  
            listaBensSelecionadosDireito.remove(cont);
            break;
        }
    }        
    target.add(panelPrincipalAnexo);
}




   THE HTML

<table width="98%" class="table table-hover"
                                style="table-layout: fixed;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th width="16%"></th>
                                        <th width="16%">Tipo</th>
                                        <th width="29%">Arquivo</th>
                                        <th width="10%">Tamanho</th>
                                        <th width="25%" class="text-left">Ações</th>
                                        <th width="4%"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr  wicket:id="anexos">
                                        <td width="16%"></td>
                                        <td width="16%"><span wicket:id="tipoArquivo"></span></td>
                                        <td width="29%"><span wicket:id="nomeAnexo"></span></td>
                                        <td width="10%"><span wicket:id="tamanhoArquivoEmMB"></span></td>
                                        <td width="25%" class="text-left">

                                            <button wicket:id="btnExcluirAnexo" 
                                                    title="Excluir" 
                                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                                    id="btnRemoverBem"">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="4%"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Your description is very confusing. Please re-phrase it.

Comment: By the name of your attributes, i think you are brazilian, am i wrong? If so, why don't you try to use the [pt version](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) of S.O.?

Comment: It ... may be next question I'll post there as well, I also participate in some other forums but people do not know well Wicket and usually do not find an answer, but I'll look there too :)... e estou postando em Inglês aqui rs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys? So I managed to find the answer here. In fact the code is right, the problem was in HTML ... The code I was using was this:
.

```
      <button wicket:id="btnExcluirAnexo" 
              title="Excluir" 
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
              id="btnRemoverBem"">
                   <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </button>
```

I just removed the id in 'Button' and went on to iterate usually ... I do not know why this problem occurred, but hey, it worked :)
.

```
<button wicket:id="btnExcluirAnexo" 
          title="Excluir" 
          class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
           I REMOVED THE ID HERE>
               <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
  </button>
```

Thanks to everyone who posted a reply.

Comment: Ronald, adding id to my code did not create any problem. I did replace my link with button as yours' and still it worked fine.

Comment: So I do not understand why it too ... maybe there is something else that is lacking, I saw the code that you passed me but still give the same mistake, only worked when I took the id of the button, I do not know as Wicket manipulated the DataView this case, I think during the iteration of the DataView the button ended up with the same internal id, each button should have a different id ... I do not know, I'm just wondering, but anyway .. . I just know it was so lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is little bit confusing. Is this what you are looking for?

Page:

```
public class TestPage4 extends WebPage {

    FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel;
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    boolean listAlreadySet = false;
    CustomerProvider customerProvider = new CustomerProvider();

    public TestPage4(final PageParameters parameters) {

        feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
        feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(feedbackPanel);

        Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        add(form);

        addFormComponents(form);
    }

    private void addFormComponents(final Form<Void> form) {


        if (!listAlreadySet){
            customerProvider = new CustomerProvider();
        } else {
            customerProvider = new CustomerProvider(customers);
        }
        DataView<Customer> dataView = new DataView<Customer>("table", customerProvider) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final Item<Customer> item) {
                final Customer customer = item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("id", customer.getId()));
                item.add(new Label("lastname", customer.getLastName()));
                item.add(new Label("firstname", customer.getFirstName()));
                item.add(new Label("age", customer.getAge()));
                AjaxFallbackLink<String> removeLink = new AjaxFallbackLink<String>("remove", Model.of(customer.getRemove())) {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        customers = customerProvider.getCustomerList();
                        Iterator<Customer> iterator = customers.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            Customer aCustomer = iterator.next();
                            if (customer.getId() == aCustomer.getId()) {
                                iterator.remove();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        target.add(form);
                        target.add(getParent());
                        target.add(findPage());
                    }
                };
                removeLink.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                item.add(removeLink);

                item.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            }
        };

        dataView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(dataView);
    }
}
```

Provider:

```
public class CustomerProvider extends SortableDataProvider<Customer, String> {

    private List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    private SortableDataProviderComparator comparator = new SortableDataProviderComparator();

    class SortableDataProviderComparator implements Comparator<Customer>, Serializable {
        public int compare(final Customer o1, final Customer o2) {
            PropertyModel<Comparable> model1 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(o1, getSort().getProperty());
            PropertyModel<Comparable> model2 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(o2, getSort().getProperty());

            int result = model1.getObject().compareTo(model2.getObject());

            if (!getSort().isAscending()) {
                result = -result;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public CustomerProvider(List<Customer> customerList) {
        Customer latest = new Customer();
        latest.setId(2000);
        latest.setLastName("LMN");
        latest.setFirstName("OPQ");
        latest.setAge(30);
        customerList.add(latest);

        setSort("firstName", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    }

    public CustomerProvider() {

        Customer latest = new Customer();
        latest.setId(1000);
        latest.setLastName("XYZ");
        latest.setFirstName("ABC");
        latest.setAge(20);
        customerList.add(latest);

        latest = new Customer();
        latest.setId(2000);
        latest.setLastName("LMN");
        latest.setFirstName("OPQ");
        latest.setAge(30);
        customerList.add(latest);


        setSort("firstName", SortOrder.ASCENDING);


    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends Customer> iterator(final long first, final long count) {

        // Get the data
        List<Customer> newList = new ArrayList<Customer>(customerList);

        // Sort the data
        Collections.sort(newList, comparator);

        // Return the data for the current page - this can be determined only after sorting
        return newList.subList((int) first, (int) (first + count)).iterator();

    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return customerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<Customer> model(final Customer customer) {

        return new IModel<Customer>() {
            @Override
            public Customer getObject() {
                return customer;
            }

            @Override
            public void setObject(Customer object) {

            }

            @Override
            public void detach() {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {

    }


    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
<form wicket:id="form">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
            <th data-field="fname">First Name</th>
            <th data-field="lname">Last Name</th>
            <th data-field="ag" data-sortable="true">Age</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr wicket:id="table">
            <td><span wicket:id="id">[contactid]</span></td>
            <td><span wicket:id="firstname">[firstname]</span></td>
            <td><span wicket:id="lastname">[lastname]</span></td>
            <td><span wicket:id="age">[lastname]</span></td>
            <td><a href="#" wicket:id="remove">[lastname]</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cont = 0;
for(ProgramaAnexo bem:list){            
    if(bemRemove.getBem().getId().intValue()==bem.getBem().getId().intValue()){  
        listaBensSelecionadosDireito.remove(cont);
        break;
    }
}
```

Like that, `cont`will always be `0`, so it will always remove the first one. Well... at least i see it that way. If `listaBensSelecionadosDireito`  is a `List<ProgramaAnexo>`, you should, w/o any problem, just `listaBensSeelcionadosDireito.remove(bemRemove)`.
Using as I said, you don't even need to use these `for`'s and `if`'s.

Comment: I didn't undestand why a suggestion of using the correct version of this site was removed. Can explain @Athafoud?

Comment: I removed it because I believe that it was not contributing to the answer. But I recommend, to add it as a comment to the initial question.